# X axis title cutting off

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, bar-chart

I tried playing with the SVG dimensions but the text is cutting off.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/35/)

Code for X-axis:

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.append("text")
.attr("x", width / 2 )
.attr("y", margin.bottom + 5)
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.style("font-size", "150%")
.text("Age in Years");
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried by increasing the margin bottom variable defined.

But that didn't work.

When i added +10 in this line `.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 10)`.

It's displaying fine now.

[**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/38/).